# How to open a file from Github Classroom on VS Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-classroom

I tried opening an assignment file from Github classroom on VS Code. But, failed.

[This is the file I tried to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pC1C.png)

And VS Code gave me this message

Open Assignment: Failed to run 'git clone'. fatal: Too many arguments. usage: git clone [] [--]  [] -v, --verbose be more verbose -q, --quiet be more quiet --progress force progress reporting --reject-shallow don't clone shallow repository -n, --no-checkout don't create a checkout --bare create a bare repository --mirror create a mirror repository (implies bare) -l, --local to clone from a local repository --no-hardlinks don't use local hardlinks, always copy -s, --shared setup as shared repository --recurse-submodules[=] initialize submodules in the clone --recursive ... alias of --recurse-submodules -j, --jobs  number of submodules cloned in parallel --template  directory from which templates will be used --reference...

[Message from VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8idP.png)

Is there anything I can do to open this? I need to do this asignment. Thanks

Comment: That screenshot of "this is the file" is not very informative for us. Did you just click that button on the Github Classroom web view of the repository? Did you try to clone a repository? Is it public, and can you link it?

Comment: I already update the picture. The name is README.md. I hope you can help me